# Currency ( SCD table ) and Request table

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables and I need to bring in the local currency to the USD value at the time of the reqiest .

```
Table 1 
Product request  / Request Date / Local Currency 
1                   01/01/2022    GBP

Table 2
Currency source / Currency Target / Effective From / Effective To / Rate 
GBP                  USD             01/12/2021       31/12/2021    1.1
GBP                  USD             01/01/2022       31/12/3039    2.2
```

The desired column for Table 1 is USD Conversion and the value being 2.2.

So in Power Query is there a way to do this column lookup and produce this column for a SCD Currency Table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Power Query, you can

- Read in your Table 2 and buffer it (so it doesn't have to be read for each row in table 1
- Use the `Table.SelectRows` method to return the desired output

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

    Source2 = Table.Buffer(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content]),
    currencyTable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,{
        {"Currency source", type text},{"Currency Target", type text},
        {"Effective From", type date},{"Effective To", type date},
        {"Rate", type number}
    }),

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Product request", Int64.Type}, {"Request Date", type date}, {"Local Currency", type text}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "USD Rate", each 
        Table.SelectRows(currencyTable, 
            (t)=>t[Currency source] = [Local Currency] and 
                 t[Effective From] <=[Request Date] and 
                 t[Effective To] >= [Request Date])[Rate]{0})
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

[image]